# Search for sequence of bytes with OllyDbg

Tags: ollydbg

I want to search for sequence of bytes in OllyDbg. Is it possible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is.

1. Right-click on the disassembly view (hex dump works too)
2. Go to `Search for` -> `Binary string`, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>

[image]